# such an expensive car

Tags: as-like

> a. I'd never buy such an expensive car as yours.
>
> b. I'd never buy an expensive car like yours.

Could one use these sentences if they are followed by something like this sentence?

I might buy an expensive car, but it won't be like yours.

I could phrase the question differently for clarity.

Do these make sense?

> a1. I'd never buy such an expensive car as yours. If I ever buy an expensive car, it will be like Harry's.
>
> b1. I'd never buy an expensive car like yours. If I ever buy an expensive car, it will be like Harry's.

The problem is that the car's being expensive isn't the issue. It is a particular kind of expensive car.

Comment: _Such an expensive car_ always implies that the price is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I say both of them are a bit not grammatical.

Since **such an** is virtually meaning (in this case):

> to so high a degree; so great (often used to emphasize a quality).

Whereas you're saying:

> I'd never buy such an expensive car as yours. If I ever buy an expensive car, it will be like Harry's.

Which doesn't mean you don't want to buy an expensive car, it just means that you don't want a specific kind of expensive car, you'd rather have Harry's car.

So I would use:

> If I was to buy an expensive car, I'd never chose to have a car like yours. I would rather have Harry's car.